# How to use custom pagination with livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I need to use custom pagination with livewire but its not working for me

i have set a public property  `$Paginator` in the livewire component.

`$Paginator` is null in the view  don't know why that is

```php
    public function getdataProperty(Request $request){
    // code ...
    
    $prelauncher = $builder->orderBy(
        $this->sortField,
        $this->sortDirection
    )->pluck('data_id')->toArray();

    if (!\is_array($prelauncher)) {
        $prelauncher = [];
    }
    $Paginator = new Paginator($prelauncher, \count($prelauncher), $this->perPage);

    $hungry = \array_chunk($prelauncher, $this->perPage);

    $fed = [];
    if (\is_array($hungry) && \array_key_exists($this->page, $hungry)) {
        $fed = $hungry[$this->page];
    }
    $totals = [];
    $counts = [];
    $launcher = Model::with([
        'user:id,username,group_id'
    ])->withCount(['thanks', 'comments'])->whereIn('data_id', $fed)->orderBy(
        $this->sortField,
        $this->sortDirection
    );
    foreach ($launcher->cursor() as $lazyCollection)
    {
        //  code...
    }
            // some more code...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the return of the $Paginator? Also, the data from the paginator can be find when you use dd($paginator)?
Please, put your front end code either, would be helpfull to see how you're trying to render on the blade.